# How to generate Lognormal random variable with given mean and standard deviation?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I need to generate 100 lognormal random variables.

Let the mean in dB is 3.0103.

Let the standard deviation in dB is 3 dB

How to generate 100 lognormal random variables?

Comment: One might start by generating 100 normal random variables with appropriately chosen parameters and then exponentiate....

Comment: If $F^{-1}:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ denotes the inverse of a CDF $F$ and $U_1,U_2,\dots$ are iid with uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ then $F^{-1}(U_1),F^{-1}(U_2),\dots$ will be a sequence of iid random variables with cdf $F$.